# calling method from NSThread

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, methods, nsthread

I am trying to call a class method in my application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: using NSThread. But strangely this method is not getting called. I have tried the below in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(parseAdContent) onThread:myThread withObject:AdvertisementView waitUntilDone:NO];
      [myThread start];
```

help me in this.

Comment: make sure this method is in the same class.

Comment: do u want to call it in main thread?

Comment: Is AdvertisementView a class or an instance of a class?

Comment: I dont want to call it in main thread. want to make this process in background.@The Saad
instance of a class @tronbabylove

Comment: Yes its in the same class. any other help will be much appreciated.

Comment: and if you want to run it in background thread then use     [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseAdContent) withObject: AdvertisementView];

Comment: and for main thread use     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(parseAdContent) withObject: AdvertisementView];

Comment: and then tell me if it invokes method by placing breakpoint

Comment: The Saad - method does not necesarily need to be in same class. That's why you got the @target param. To specify the target object where the new thread selector will run.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a separate thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(yourSelector:) toTarget:yourTarget withObject:objectYouWishToPassAsParameter];
```

The selector you specify will automatically get executed on a new thread.

Particular example for your code:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseAdContent:) toTarget:self withObject:AdvertisementView];
```

And your thread selector should look like this:

```
- (void)parseAdContent:(id)obj {
    NSAutoreleasePool *threadPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // Your background thread code here

    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: OP said that he's trying to call a class method. Shouldn't target be [self class]?

Comment: @tronbabylove Thanks for your reply, but I am not getting wat is expected. Target cant be self or self class, why because I am having the method in another class called Adview where AdvertisementView is the instance variable of that class in applicationDelagate class. anymore help please

Comment: @user1188275 It's located in the Adview class - so is it a class method or an instance method?

Comment: for the method example I used above (- (void)parseAdContent:(id)obj), target is self, not [self class]. If you were to use a static method (ex: + (id)someMethod:(id)param) target would indeed be [self class]. My example should have been descriptive enough]

Answer (score 0):

You want to call a class method, but this call is trying to invoking self's -parseAdContent:. I don't know what class this is being called in, but either way, the target here is the instance variable self and not a class. Something like this is probably more what you are looking for.

```
[myThread initWithTarget:[self class] selector:@selector(parseAdContent) object:AdvertisementView];
```

EDIT: So if the method is a class method in the Adview class, just change the target to the Adview class...

```
[myThread initWithTarget:[Adview class] selector:@selector(parseAdContent) object:AdvertisementView];
```

But if it is an instance method in the Adview class, then the target will be the instance of variable of type Adview - AdvertisementView, right?

```
[myThread initWithTarget:AdvertisementView selector:@selector(parseAdContent) object:AdvertisementView];
```

But this wouldn't make sense, you wouldn't call an instance method and pass the instance as a parameter to its own method... The target is the object for which you are invoking the selector. The object: parameter is used the selector's argument.

I'm assuming that this is a class method as you stated originally, in which case the first of these two calls should work.

Comment: I tried both of your example, making my method as class and instance method but the execution cycle does not pass through the method. I am totaly lost. fixed with this for the past two days !!. Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: @user1188275 Another thing I noticed is that you are passing a parameter to the method (AdvertisementView), but you did not include the ':' in your selector tag. It should be "selector:(parseAdContent:)" I think adding the colon makes it a completely different selector - try adding it and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @user1188275 One more note - according to the Apple Docs, "the selector must take only one argument and must not have a return value." So make sure that parseAdContent is not returning anything.